# Why v$.$model is always null?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuelidate

I'm trying to update my Vue 3 app to Vuelidate v2 and I cannot understand why the `v$` object created with `useVuelidate` doesn't return the `$model`. It was not a problem in Vuelidate v.0.x. This makes debugging cumbersome.

Example:

```
<template><input v-model="test"/></template>
<script>
import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core'
import { required } from '@vuelidate/validators'

export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, ctx) {
    const test = ref('')
    const v$ = useVuelidate({ test: { required } }, { test: test })

    return {
      v$,
      test,
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

`$v.$model` in Vuelidate v.0.7.7: `{ test: ''}` (expected)
`v$.$model` in Vuelidate v.2.0.3: `null`

`v$` in Vue DevTools:
[image]

Comment: Instead of looking at the root of the object, look for the name of the property being validated.  It will have it's own `$model` value.  Does `v$.test.$model` provide what you need?

Comment: You've already got a model, { test: test }. If you didn't keep a reference to it then fix this

Comment: @yoduh yes, `v$.test.$model` returns what's expected, but what then `v$.$model` is for?